# How to convert a promise to an observable?

Tags: angular, ionic2, angular2-observables

I am working on ionic 2 project. I am able to return all contacts in the device/phone. But I used the promise code which has very slow performance because of single request at a time. Now, I want change that promise code to an observable. Please help me to solve this.

```
findContact(searchKey){
    if(searchKey.target.value == "" || searchKey.target.value == undefined || searchKey.target.value == null){
        this.contactSelected = false;
    } else{
        this.contactSelected = true;
    }
    let options = {
        multiple: true,
        hasPhoneNumber: true,
        filter: searchKey.target.value
    }
    let cantactFields = ['displayName', 'phoneNumbers'];
    Contacts.find(cantactFields, options).then(res => {
            this.contactResults = res;
    }, (er) => {
        console.log(er);
    })
}
```

`Contacts.find()` is the method where I used the promises. And this method returns the contacts very slowly.

Comment: You're likely having an XY problem, if the method is 'slow', there's nothing that observables can help with. Both promises and observables are capable of processing multiple requests simultaneously. And the question doesn't show relevant code.

Answer (score 3):

You Can Use `Observable.fromPromise` To wrap your promise in observable.

Something like this can be done to wrap your promise in observable.

```
findContact(searchKey){
    if(searchKey.target.value == "" || searchKey.target.value == undefined || searchKey.target.value == null){
        this.contactSelected = false;
    } else{
        this.contactSelected = true;
    }
    let options = {
        multiple: true,
        hasPhoneNumber: true,
        filter: searchKey.target.value
    }
    let cantactFields = ['displayName', 'phoneNumbers'];
    var promise =Contacts.find(cantactFields, options).then(res => {
        this.contactResults = res;
    }, (er) => {
        console.log(er);
    })
    return PromiseObservable.create(promise); //     Observable.fromPromise(promise)
}
```

Hope This HElps

Comment: I think it will also produce the same result. Because you are sending the request by promise. Then you are returning the response into observable. Am I right?

Comment: Yes. It will resolve promise & then convert it observable. if you want to use observables then you will have to update the API in service.

Comment: But that is predefined method. http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/contacts/ see this link about that method. If you get any other thought, please share with me.